How to exclude files from being indexed in Visual Studio 2022 in Open Folder Development?
When opening my project Visual Studio tries to index all the files in the project, and basically becomes unusable as it becomes incredibly slow / unresponsive. In the project folder there is a /xml folder that contains cache results and has thousands of subfolders and files.
When opening the project in Visual Studio 2022 by File -> Open -> Website, Visual Studio shows the following background task:

This task runs for hours without completing, thus making development virtually impossible.
How can I exclude the /xml and all its subfolders from being indexed / searched by Visual Studio?
I have already tried disabling all extensions and repairing Visual Studio.
I have also tried to add a VSWorkspaceSettings.json file containing:
{
  "ExcludedItems" : [
    "xml/*"
   ]
}

Neither of these have made any difference.

I created an "ASP.NET Core Web Application (Razor Pages)". I added a /xml folder to the project and added 5,000 subfolders and files to the xml folder through a script. Then I opened the project in Visual Studio 2022 through File -> Open -> Website as you said, but I didn't reproduce the problem you encountered. Please tell me if the above steps are correct, so that I can try to reproduce the problem and then deal with it.

@CodyLiang It looks like I grossly underestimated the amount of files. We have 4.2 million files, 40,000 folders, and a total size of 10GB. So its understandable why Visual Studio struggles. I can work around the issue by opening the subfolders that I want to work on individually.
